# Как сделать увеличение изображения в php?

Tags: php, изображения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли подручными средствами php сделать увеличение изображения и все стандартные операции над изображением без явы? И если можно, подскажите, с чего начинать...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если требуется изменить саму картинку (файл), то Вам может помочь [библиотека GD](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.image.php), в частности, для изменения размеров изображения - [imagecopyresampled](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecopyresampled.php)

Если речь идет об отображении в браузере, то изменение исходного изображения вряд ли нужно, достаточно <img width=".." height=".." /> или аналогичные CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Можно растянуть изображение ([imagecopyresampled](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)) и сохранить его на диске, но качество при этом потеряется.

Answer (score 0):

Простой подход - это взять библиотеку [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/old/MainPage). Тогда

```
$img = $_GET['img'];
$width = $_GET['width'];    
$scaled = wiImage::load($img)->resize($scaled);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');    
echo $scaled->asString('jpg', 80);
```